# Annotations in Nashorn

Tags: java-8, nashorn

Is it possible to apply annotations to method parameters in Nashorn (JavaScript)?

I want users to be able to define their own classes that can later be injected using [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice), which generally requires the use of annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to add Java annotations to Java subclasses implemented in Nashorn JavaScript (assuming that was your question!)

Comment: Yeah...Nashorn has a decent number of syntax additions, but unfortunately annotations is not among them. I ended up indirectly exposing access to the injector so the JS could "ask" for the dependencies it needed.